# useContext in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've been trying to use the context hook in React Native, but it doesn't seem to work, it returns undefined. However, when I use `<Context.Consumer>` it does work fine, do you know if useContext is supported in React Native?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

useContext is absolutely supported in react native.
Use React.createContext() to create the context.

```js
export const AppStateContext = React.createContext();

const AppStateProvider = props => {

  const contextValue={...yourContext}

  return (
    <AppStateContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {props.children}
    </AppStateContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Wrap your app like so.

```js
<AppStateProvider>
    <App />
</AppStateProvider>
```

Then you can access the context in your nested component with the useContext hook.

```js
import {AppStateContext} from './AppStateProvider';

function YourComponent(props) {
  const {context} = useContext(AppStateContext)
  
  ...
    return (
      <View>
      ...
      </View>
  );
}
```