# Passing data from first screen to third screen

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-code

I have sent data from first screen to second screen using route.params. Now I want to send data from first screen to third screen. I want to send registered email from first screen to the profile in third screen.
How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what navigation library are you using?

Comment: You can do it by useContext hook. look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58060118/usecontext-in-react-native

Comment: You can pass any values in props.

Comment: useContext did work out! Thanks - Lah Ezcen

Comment: used redux for centralized state management